# There is a problem with the SQL query that I want to solve

Tags: sql

Music Streaming (TimeId, SongId, PlatformId,
Numberofstreamings, Numberoflikes)
Time(TimeId, date, month, 2M, 3M, 6M, year, dayofTheWeek)
Song(SongId, Song, album, classic, indie, pop, rock)
UserLocation (UserLocationId, province, region, country)

For each song and month, compute the following metrics:
• the total number of streamings
• the cumulative total number of streamings since the beginning of the year
• assign a rank to each song, separately for each album, based on the monthly
number of streamings (rank 1st the most streamed song of the album for each
month).

**The code**

```
SELECT month, song,
SUM (NumberOfStreamings),
SUM( SUM(NumberOfStreamings)) OVER (PARTITION BY songId, year
ORDER BY month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY album, month ORDER BY
SUM(NumberOfStreamings) DESC),
FROM Song s, Time T, MusicStreaming MS
WHERE S. SongId=MS. SongId AND T.Timeid=MS. Timeid
GROUP BY song, songId, month, year, album;
```

If you can modify the code and tell me what is wrong please

When I write the query it doesn't do what I want as described in the prompts

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Can you help me to edit the code because I tried my best I couldn't do anything

I am just a beginner in this field

Comment: `FROM Song s JOIN MusicStreaming MS ON S.SongId = MS.SongId JOIN Time T ON ...`